Google map is shaking while marker is moving on the surface of the map (Flutter + Firebase realtime database)
I'm using google_maps_flutter, flutter_polyline_points and firebase_database packages in my Flutter project.
I have another app which is for driver and it's live location is shared with firebase realtime database and I watch the location changes in this app.
Everything is ok, except, when location update the map is jamping not moving smoothly.
here is my code:
This is map widget and streamBuilder where I watch location changes
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var mover = Provider.of<TrackingProvider>(context, listen: false).mover;
    var orderId = Provider.of<TrackingProvider>(context, listen: false).orderId;
  
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: db.ref("mover_${mover['user']['id']}_$orderId").onValue,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          Map<dynamic, dynamic>? newLocation;
          // Cancel the previous debounce operation if it exists
          _debounceOperation?.cancel();

          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if ((snapshot.data as DatabaseEvent).snapshot.value != null) {
              newLocation = (snapshot.data as DatabaseEvent).snapshot.value as Map;
              _moverLatLng =
                  LatLng(newLocation['latitude'], newLocation['longitude']);
              _updateMoverMarker(context, newLocation);

              _debounceOperation = CancelableOperation.fromFuture(
                _updateMoverPolyline(context, newLocation),
                onCancel: () => debugPrint('Debounce operation canceled.'),
              );

              _watchMoverLocation(context, newLocation);
            }
          }
          return Stack(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                    (isTablet(context) ? 0.92 : 0.88),
                child: GoogleMap(
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: LatLng(49.28365819800792, -123.10308363551924),
                    zoom: 13.4746,
                  ),
                  myLocationEnabled: false,
                  myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                  tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
                  mapToolbarEnabled: false,
                  compassEnabled: false,
                  scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
                  zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                  zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                  markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
                  polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(polylines.values),
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
                    _mapController = controller;
                    pickupIcon = await getPickupMarker(context);
                    destIcon = await getDestinationMarker(context);
                    await _initMarkers();
                    await _getPolyline(_pickupAddress);
                    List<LatLng> list = [
                      LatLng(_pickupLat!, _pickupLng!),
                      LatLng(_destLat!, _destLng!)
                    ];
                    _setBounds(list);
                  },
                  onTap: (LatLng latLng) {
                    //_setBounds();
                  },
                ),
              ),
              MapButtons(),
              mapBottomBar(context, newLocation, mover),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

Here I clear plylines and update the bounds
 _watchMoverLocation(context, newLocation) async {
    if (newLocation.isNotEmpty) {
      polylineCoordinates.clear();
      if (newLocation['status'] == "toPickup") {
        List<LatLng> list = [_moverLatLng, LatLng(_pickupLat!, _pickupLng!)];
        _setBounds(list);
      }
      if (newLocation['status'] == "toDestination") {
        List<LatLng> list = [_moverLatLng, LatLng(_destLat!, _destLng!)];
        _setBounds(list);
      }
    }
  }

Here I update the marker
  void _updateMoverMarker(context, locationData) async {
    if (locationData != null) {
      Uint8List? customMarker =
          Provider.of<TrackingProvider>(context, listen: false).moverMarker;
      MarkerId markerId = MarkerId("Mover");

      final latLng =
          LatLng(locationData['latitude'], locationData['longitude']);

      final animation =
          _moverLatLng != const LatLng(0.0, 0.0) && _moverLatLng != latLng
              ? Tween(begin: _moverLatLng, end: latLng)
                  .animate(_animationController)
              : ConstantTween<LatLng>(latLng).animate(_animationController);

      _moverLatLng = latLng;

      _mapController?.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLng(_moverLatLng));

      _animationController.reset();
      _animationController.forward();

      _animationController.addListener(() {
        Marker marker = Marker(
          markerId: markerId,
          position: animation.value,
          zIndex: 2,
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(customMarker!),
          infoWindow:
              InfoWindow(title: "Mover", snippet: "${locationData['name']}"),
        );
        markers[markerId] = marker;
      });
    }
  }

And this function update polyline
  Future<PolylineResult> _updateMoverPolyline(context, moverLocation) async {
    String address;
    double latitude, longitude;
    if (moverLocation['status'] == "toDestination") {
      address = _destAddress!;
      latitude = _destLat!;
      longitude = _destLng!;
    } else {
      address = _pickupAddress!;
      latitude = _pickupLat!;
      longitude = _pickupLng!;
    }

    PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
      mapKey,
      PointLatLng(moverLocation['latitude'], moverLocation['longitude']),
      PointLatLng(latitude, longitude),
      travelMode: TravelMode.driving,
      wayPoints: [PolylineWayPoint(location: "$address")],
    );

    var pts = [];
    if (result.points.isNotEmpty) {
      moverPolylineCoordinates = [];
      moverPolylineCoordinates.clear();
      result.points.forEach((PointLatLng point) {
        pts.add(point);
        moverPolylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
      });
    }
    _addMoverPolyLine();
    return result;
  }

Please correct me if I'm doing anything wrong

how are you requesting the coordinates from the realtime database?

@Yrll you see in code at first section I used streamBuilder:
StreamBuilder(
stream: db.ref("mover_${mover['user']['id']}_$orderId").onValue,
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
